# Write a truncated normal distribution function using R

Tags: r, statistics

Hi I'm trying to use R to write a dtnorm () and rtnorm () function. (the same ones in the msm package)

here is the code i wrote:

```
rtnorm<-function(mu=0,sd=1,a=-Inf,b=Inf)
{
F<-runif(n=length(mu))
Fa<-pnorm((a-mu)/sd,0,sd=1)
Fa[a== -Inf] <-0
Fb<-pnorm((b-mu)/sd,0,sd=1)
Fb[b==Inf]<-1
y<-mu+sd*qnorm(F*(Fb-Fa)+Fa)
y
}
```

however, when I test it,it only gives me one number in return, but when I use the msm package, it gives me 10 different numbers in return. how should i modify this code?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you set `mu=0`. This has length of 1. Try setting `mu=rep(0,10)` to get back 10 numbers. For example:

```
rtnorm<-function(mu,sd=1,a=-Inf,b=Inf)
{
  F<-runif(n=length(mu))
  Fa<-pnorm((a-mu)/sd,0,sd=1)
  Fa[a== -Inf] <-0
  Fb<-pnorm((b-mu)/sd,0,sd=1)
  Fb[b==Inf]<-1
  y<-mu+sd*qnorm(F*(Fb-Fa)+Fa)
  y
}

rtnorm(mu=rep(0,10))
```